# Using Buttons to Scroll in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, button, scroll

I'm developing an app for young children and research shows that it's easier for them to hold a button to scroll as opposed to actually swiping to scroll.

How do you allow scrolling to be controlled by buttons? For example, I'm trying to implement a horizontal scroll (landscape view) where on the left margin is a left arrow button and on the right margin is a right arrow button. Pressing on either button will scroll in that respective direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Recyclerview` with `Horizontal` `LinearLayoutManager` and `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)` method of recyclerview.

`LinearLayoutManager` has many methods can help you:

`findFirstVisibleItemPosition`, `findLastVisibleItemPosition`, ...